# Avoid repetition of same if case for different cases

Tags: java

I have the following code:

```
if (product != null) {
    //tryToGetProductFromOnePlace 
}
if (product != null) {
    //tryToGetProductFromSecondPlace 
}
if (product != null) {
    //tryToGetProductFromThirdPlace 
}
if (product != null) {
    //tryToGetProductFromFourthPlace
}
return product;
```

I want to refactor this code to look better but I have no ideas. I can't use recursion since the logic of getting the product is different all the time. I can't return it in the if case since I need to get the value and only if all these 4 combinations are not ok then to return null. Any suggestion of how to improve the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your methods to return `Optional` values instead of `null` and then chain them using `Optional`'s `or` method:

```
return this.tryToGetProductFromOnePlace()
    .or(this::tryToGetProductFromSecondPlace)
    .or(this::tryToGetProductFromThirdPlace)
    .or(this::tryToGetProductFromFourthPlace);
```

If for some reason you need to preserve the external interface of returning `null` instead of `Optional.empty()` for an absent value, you can add `.orElse(null)` to the end of the call chain.

Comment: Since I am not using java 11 I did the following:


`private Product evaluateProduct(Offer offer, String productId) {
        return getProductVendorForCollectiveTreaty(offer, productId)
                .orElse(getProductVendorForParentMasterTreaty(offer, productId)
                .orElse(getProductVendorForMasterTreaty(offer, productId)
                .orElse(getProductVendorForSubParentMasterTreaty(offer, productId)
                .orElse(null))));
    }`

Comment: Actually what I was suppose to do:

`private ProductVendorResponse evaluateProductVendor(Offer offer, String productId) {
        return tryToGetProductFromOnePlace()
                .orElseGet(() -> tryToGetProductFromSecondePlace()
                        .orElseGet(() -> tryToGetProductFromThirdPlace()
                                .orElseGet(() -> tryToGetProductFromFourthPlace()
                                        .orElse(null))));
    }`